# "Combine" events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

### TL;DR:

How can I combine the three "touch" browser events with a delay to emulate a "long press" event and make it available for jQuery to attach to any appropriate DOM element?

### Full Question

Since I believe iPad and other touchscreen devices most reliably only trigger the `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend` events, I guess a framework - of one level of complexity or another - is needed in order to react to events like gestures, long presses, and multiple touches.

I'm not ready to add one of the mobile frameworks in my current project, so to that end, I've added a bit of code that seems to work well enough at emulating a "long" press, and would allow someone to come along and either trigger the predefined handler or add an additional handler for such an event:

```
var touchTimeout = null;
var $element = null;

$('div#SomeIdOnADIVElementOrTwo')
    .on('touchstart', function(){
        $element = $(this);
        //not sure if this is absolutely necessary, but it was based off an Internet resource found when it didn't work like I wanted it to - and it works, so...
        touchTimeout = setTimeout(
            function($element){
                return function(){
                    $($element).trigger('longpress');
                };
            }($element), 1000
        );
    })
    .on('touchend touchmove', function(){
        clearTimeout(touchTimeout);
    })
    .on('longpress', function(){
        $(this).dblclick();
    });
```

This, however, is currently restricted to whatever selector or jQuery object I pass in to the original jQuery omni-function call on the first line (in my case, a div with the id `SomeIdOnADIVElementOrTwo`). What I'd like to do is define the three events `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend` (along with the delay/timeout, etc) as a standard "event" that someone could "handle" on any "touchable" DOM object.

Is this as simple as changing my selector to `*`? I'm pretty sure this would work conceptually, but I can't help but think that could very well be unmanageable on a page with a large number of elements - or am I possibly confused as to how event handlers are registered? Would I perhaps be better off extending jQuery with a `.longPress()` function (in the same vein as the `.click()` and `.dblClick()` functions)? Is this unfeasible or impossible? Is it incredibly simple and I'm missing something?